# Sending microphone input over Remote Desktop 7.0

Tags: windows, audio, remote-desktop, recording, microphone

I am using Remote Desktop 7 (the new version that came out with Windows 7) to control a Windows XP Pro machine. I have selected "Record from this computer" in the Remote Audio settings. When I connect to the machine, go to the control panel, open the sound panel, and go to the audio tab, I find that the default sound playback device is "Microsoft RDP Audio Driver". However, there is no default sound recording device.

As expected, my IP phone thinks there is no recording device. If I am sitting in front of the computer with a mic plugged in, it works just fine.

Has anybody else been able to get this work appropriately? Is there anything that I have to setup on the XP machine to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** As John T pointed out below, you have to be connecting to a Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate machine for this to work. I've also found out that Multi-monitor support has the same requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When redirecting microphone output over RDP 7.0, it must be sent to another Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate machine. [This comment on the Windows 7 blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2009/05/11/what-s-new-in-remote-audio-for-windows-7.aspx#9872894) has more info.

If you'd like to send microphone output to XP over RDP, check out [Remote Sound](http://www.elusiva.com/products/remotesound.aspx) or [Sound over RDP](http://www.sound-over-rdp.com/). Both solutions are shareware, try before you buy.

Comment: John, thank you for your quick reply. I saw that comment, but hoped that it wasn't true since I hadn't seen anything else in the docs for remote desktop (yes, I know... the commenter is actually from MSFT and I have no reason not to trust him). Thanks for the links to the two products. I'll take a closer look at them.

Comment: No problem! Let me know how things go.

Comment: This is for sending the local recording device to the remote server - what about using the remote server's recording device? Why would that be disabled?